# I am testing a python-gst program from github and am stuck with a blackscreen

Tags: python-gstreamer

I am using py-gst`to parse the h264 video from`srcfile` which should give me split video in order to show on VR headset. However, I just have a black screen with nothing. Here is program on github:https://github.com/natxopedreira/fpv-stream-to-vr.

Can anyone help? Is the pipeline wrong?

I have changed `fdsrc` to `filescr localtion="test.264"` when testing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

input_path = 'wifibroadcast'
oculus_width = 1920
oculus_height = 1200

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    input_path = sys.argv[1]

# Set output_port to an output name recognized by xrandr to override where
# we output the video - if output_port is None we'll look for
# the first monitor that is 1920x1080.  If not None, we'll ignore
# oculus_width and oculus_height and assume the resolution reported by
# xrandr with half of the screen area for each eye.
#output_port = 'HDMI1'
output_port = None

if input_path == 'wifibroadcast':
    input_pipeline = 'filescr location="/home/mi/test.264" ! h264parse ! avdec_h264'
else:
    input_pipeline = 'v4l2src device=' + input_path + ' ! deinterlace'

# Don't write the stream to disk by default
dump_pipeline = ''
#dump_pipeline = 'orig. ! queue ! filesink location=capture.raw'

import subprocess, re, gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject, Gtk, Gdk

# Needed for window.get_xid(), xvimagesink.set_window_handle(), respectively:
from gi.repository import GdkX11, GstVideo

class GTK_Main(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h, x, y):
        window = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        window.set_decorated(False)
        window.set_size_request(1280, 800)
        window.move(x, y)

        #window.resize(w/2, h/2)
        #window.fullscreen()

        window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit, "WM destroy")
        window.connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
        self.gst_window = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    #self.gst_window.set_size_request(1060, 397)
        window.add(self.gst_window)
        window.show_all()

        # TODO: disable screen saver (gsettings?)

        self.per_eye_w = 1280 / 2
        self.left_x = 0
        self.right_x = 1280 / 2
        self.offset_x = 0

        # Set up the gstreamer pipeline
        self.player = Gst.parse_launch(input_pipeline + ' ! ' +
                'tee name=orig ! ' +
                'videoscale add-borders=1 ! ' +
                'video/x-raw,width=' + str(self.per_eye_w) + ',height=' +
                str(h) + ' !  ' +
                'tee name=tee ! ' +
                'queue ! ' +
                'videomixer name=mixer ! ' +
                'xvimagesink double-buffer=false sync=false ' +
                'tee. ! ' +
                'queue ! ' +
                'mixer. ' +
                dump_pipeline)
        self.mixer = self.player.get_by_name('mixer')
        bus = self.player.get_bus()
        bus.add_signal_watch()
        bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
        bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
        bus.connect("sync-message::element", self.on_sync_message)

        self.xpos_update()

        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        sys.stderr.write('Gstreamer pipeline created and started\n')

    def xpos_update(self):
        # TODO: reimplement x offset in a way that one eye's video never
        # shows in the other eye's half of the screen

        sink0 = self.mixer.get_static_pad('sink_0')
        sink1 = self.mixer.get_static_pad('sink_1')

        sink0.set_property('xpos', self.left_x + self.offset_x)
        sink1.set_property('xpos', self.right_x + self.offset_x)

    def on_message(self, bus, message):
        t = message.type
        if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
            sys.stderr.write('Stream ended\n')
            Gtk.main_quit()
        elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
            err, debug = message.parse_error()
            sys.stderr.write('Error: ' + str(err) + '\n' + str(debug))
            Gtk.main_quit()

    def on_sync_message(self, bus, message):
        if message.get_structure().get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
            imagesink = message.src

            Gdk.threads_enter()
            imagesink.set_window_handle(
                    self.gst_window.get_property('window').get_xid())
            Gdk.threads_leave()
            sys.stderr.write('Gstreamer synced\n')

    def on_key_press(self, widget, event):
        keyname = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)

        if keyname in [ 'q', 'Q', 'Escape' ]:
            Gtk.main_quit()
        elif keyname == 'Left':
            self.offset_x -= 4
            self.xpos_update()
        elif keyname == 'Right':
            self.offset_x += 4
            self.xpos_update()
        elif keyname == 'Up':
            self.left_x -= 1
            self.right_x += 1
            self.xpos_update()
        elif keyname == 'Down':
            self.left_x += 1
            self.right_x -= 1
            self.xpos_update()

# Find the selected screen using xrandr directly
#
# Should either use one of the libxrandr bindings libraries but none is popular
# enough to be packaged by distributions, or use gtk.gdk:
# scr = gtk.gdk.screen_get_default()
# n = scr.get_n_monitors()
# [ scr.get_monitor_plug_name(i) for i in range(0, n) ]
# [ scr.get_monitor_geometry(i) for i in range(0, n) ]
# also subscribe to scr signal "monitor-changed"
#
# We'd still need to use xrandr to actually rotate the screen, it seems.

#p = subprocess.Popen([ 'xrandr', '-q' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
#output = p.communicate()[0]
#monitor_line = None
#resolution_str1 = ' ' + str(oculus_width) + 'x' + str(oculus_height) + '+'
#resolution_str2 = ' ' + str(oculus_height) + 'x' + str(oculus_width) + '+'

#for line in output.split('\n'):
#    if output_port and line.startswith(output_port):
#        monitor_line = line
#        break
#    if not output_port and (resolution_str1 in line or resolution_str2 in line):
#        monitor_line = line
#        break

#if not monitor_line:
#    if output_port:
#        sys.stderr.write(outout_port + ' not found\n')
#    else:
#        sys.stderr.write('No screen found with the right resolution\n')
#    sys.exit(-1)

#if not output_port:
#    output_port = monitor_line.split()[0]
#if 'disconnected' in monitor_line:
#    sys.stderr.write(output_port + ' seems to be disconnected\n')
#    sys.exit(-1)

#match = re.search(r'\b([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)\b', monitor_line)
#w, h, x, y = [ int(n) for n in match.groups() ]

#sys.stderr.write('Using ' + output_port + ' for output\n')

# If screen seems to be in vertical/portrait mode (height > width), rotate it
#if h > w:
#    sys.stderr.write('Setting --rotate left\n')
#    subprocess.check_call([ 'xrandr',
#            '--output', output_port,
#            '--rotate', 'left' ])
#    w, h = h, w
#
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
GTK_Main(1280, 800, 0, 0)
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: https://github.com/natxopedreira/fpv-stream-to-vr

Comment: I just want one video stream and duplicate it to a side by side video chould show on the gtk window